# Hahn-Banach extension of Cauchy formula

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A(\mathbb D)$ denote the disk algebra of the unit disk $\mathbb D$. Let $z_0\in\mathbb D$. Clearly, the linear form $\varphi$ on $A(\mathbb D)$, defined by
$$
\varphi(f)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz = f(z_0)
$$
is continuous with norm $1$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, $\varphi$ admits an extension $\psi$ to
$C(\mathbb T)$, the set of continuous functions on the unit circle (endowed with the sup norm), still of norm $1$.

Is there an explicit formula for $\psi$ ?

Comment: $\psi(f)=P[f](z_0)$, where $P[f]$ is the Poisson integral.

Comment: You can read the book, Real and Complex analysis, of Walter Rudin to learn it.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich, Thanks !